# simpleHttp causing 'unsupported browser response?'

Tags: http, haskell

I'm executing a simpleHttp request to a https domain, yet the response html is showing 'unsupported browser' messages -- i believe this is because simpleHttp does not support HTTPS.

My function:

```
import Network.HTTP.Simple

makeRequest :: IO LAZ.ByteString
makeRequest = do
  response <- simpleHttp "https://www.example.com"
  return (response)
```

Which haskell libraries support https?

Comment: Hard to tell - maybe those messages are supposed to be hidden by Javascript one it is run? Try opening the same web page in a browser and inspect the source to see if it is different. The web server might also generate a different page for every user-agent (which is very very bad, if that's the case).

Comment: @chi I've tested the site using 'request' library in Node.js and it works fine. So I assume its to do with the http driver Network.HTTP is using. Perhaps I can try Network.Wreq, but the documentation is based on lens' which i haven't covered yet!

Comment: @chi turns out only very very basic understanding of lens is required for Wreq, and I've found my solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wreq](http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/tutorial.html) provides a very easy to follow tutorial on http/s requests using basic lens syntax.

A https compatible request is as simple as:

```
main = do
  r <- get "https://www.example.com"
```

Response statuses and bodies can be accessed respectively:

```
  r ^. responseStatus . statusCode
  r ^. responseBody
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't compile. Even adding in the `LAZ` import, the `Network.HTTP.Simple` module does not provide the `simpleHttp` function. You can do this with `httpLBS`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LAZ

makeRequest :: IO LAZ.ByteString
makeRequest = do
response <- httpLBS "https://www.example.com"
return (getResponseBody response)

main :: IO ()
main = makeRequest >>= LAZ.putStr
```

Or by using the `simpleHttp` function from `Network.HTTP.Conduit`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LAZ

makeRequest :: IO LAZ.ByteString
makeRequest = simpleHttp "https://www.example.com"

main :: IO ()
main = makeRequest >>= LAZ.putStr
```

Note that `wreq` uses the same HTTP engine under the surface as http-conduit (http-client). My guess is that you were originally trying to use one of the functions from http-client itself, but I'm not sure what that code would have looked like.